# How to add Text to a NSTextView?

Tags: c#, xcode, visual-studio, nstextview

I am working on a project and I need to add text to an NSTextView object. I have seen other posts that say I need to use the "Value" parameter but when I try that it errors out. here's the code to show what I mean.

```cs
TextView.Value = "String Value";
```

I am using Visual Studio and XCode to develop, and I'm using a Cocoa app template. Thank you for any and all help!

Comment: To add text to an NSTextView, you can use the insertText("") method. For example, to insert the string "Hello, World!" into an NSTextView, you would use the following code:
textView.insertText("Hello, World!") replace all you need to use textview.string. If you find the solution, you could mark it as the answer.

Comment: The insertText method does not accept a string value, it accepts 3 different sets of things, 
I. NSObject
II &. III. NSObject and a NSRange
So it's not letting me just input a string.

Answer (score 0):

To add text to an NSTextView object in a Cocoa app, you should use the `string` property, like so:

```
TextView.string = "String Value"
```

Comment: The string parameter is read-only so I can't set it through that.